# Azure-hosted Windows Cluster not pingable across VPN

Tags: vpn, azure, windows-cluster

I have a simple 2 node Windows cluster hosted in Azure with a VPN connection to this network.

From my machine, I can ping the local nodes via their internal IPs (10.0.0.20, 10.0.0.21)

I cannot ping the cluster's virtual IP: 10.0.0.15, although I can do that from either of the nodes themselves.

I cannot work out how to expose this cluster IP across my VPN connection.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible and what I could do to make it work?

Thank you!

Comment: ICMP ping is not supported. Are you using TCPPing?

Comment: What @proteus said, you can't ping the ILB IP address. The nodes can ping it because you have that address configured as secondary on your interfaces (so in reality you are pinging yourself).